# One activity get data from two activities in android

Tags: android

I want to implement that the activity gets data from two activities in android. Detail:

In total have three activities. `Activity_0` has two `EditTexts`, `EditText_1` and `EditText_2`. When I click `EditText_1`,it link to `Activity_1` and select data ,then go back to `Activity_0` and pass value to `EditText_1`,when I click `EditText_2`,it link to `Activity_2` and select data,then  go back to `Activity_0` and pass value to `EditText_2`. The problem is that `Activity_0` will be refresh when I click second `EditText`, so I only get one value every time though I click two.

Comment: save value in sharepreference.

Comment: You can only pass data though one Intent to a single Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the SharedPreferences to save the data which can be use anywhere where you want to show.
  For storing data in SharedPreferences you may use these lines of code in Activity_1 and Activity_2 .

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString("Name, n);
            editor.commit();
```

For  fetching data to show in Activity_0 you can use below lines:-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("Name", null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code is available. At beginning,I try to create  respectively different PREFERENCES in Activity_1 and Activity_2 ,  it did not work ,but it is available when i use the same  PREFERENCES and just get them in my Activity_0.

Answer (score 0):

Ya ...it's possible ...you have to pass the intent on edittext `onClickListener` along with `putExtra`

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity_0.this, Activity_1.class); 
i.putExtra("xyz", xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way i can tell you is `startActivityForResult`.

1. write this in onClick of edittext1  `startActivityForResult(new Intent(context, EditText1SelectActivity.class), 1);`
2. set value when you are selecting anything from `EditText1SelectActivity`

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("value", "selected value");
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();
   ```
3. and again in your mainActivity get that value in `onActivityResult()`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           Bundle res = data.getExtras();
           edittext1.setText(res.getString("value"));
       }
   }
   ```

follow above procedure for edittext2 also but with **different request code** in `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Oh,I just know there are so many ways to achieve my function,thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your first value somewhere, so there are many ways to do it.
for example you can save it in [sharedpreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)   or you can use `onSaveInstanceState()` method of Activity_0, to do it you can read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) page about recreating an Activity.